# Proper usage of "bogus"

Tags: register

I know what *bogus* means, but I don't know if it is appropriate to use it in certain formal contexts. Specifically, I'm working on a grant application and I found myself writing the following sentence.

> Overall, little effort has been devoted to systematically tracking the distribution of certain variables across datasets. This has led to the formulation of a number of bogus generalizations.

Does this sound too inappropriate/informal/condescending/pejorative?

Comment: But what about the bogus use of "proper"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with "bogus" there is that it is a very imprecise word, and can often mean "I don't like it". For example, in [Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096928/), the words "excellent" and "bogus" were used as antonyms of each other.

For a grant, I'd probably switch to something closer to the specific meaning you are going for, like perhaps "invalid" or "misleading".

Answer (score 1):

Before "Bill and Ted," "bogus" was a perfectly acceptable word for "false." In the context of a formal statement or report, it will be recognized in its original form. (It's fine.)